# Create form in Controller using Sonata field type

Tags: ajax, symfony, controller, symfony-forms, sonata-admin

In Symfony admin, I have a form, where the second field type depends on the `ChoiceField` value selected. The second field can be of Symfony **Url** field type or sonata provided **sonata_type_model_list** field type.

I have created an ajax request to My Bundle Controller to return the form, which contains the needed field.

```
> /src/MyBundle/Controller/MyController.php

namespace MyBundle\Controller

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller\CRUDController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataInfo;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;

class MyController extends CRUDController
{
    public function getFieldAction()
  {
    //getting the value of choice field
    $type = $this->get('request')->get('type'); 

    //sonata.admin.reference is a service name of ReferenceBundle admin class
        $fieldDescription = $this->admin->getModelManager()
         ->getNewFieldDescriptionInstance($this->admin->getClass(), 'reference');
        $fieldDescription->setAssociationAdmin($this->container->get('sonata.admin.reference'));
        $fieldDescription->setAdmin($this->admin);
        $fieldDescription->setAssociationMapping(array(
            'fieldName' => 'reference',
            'type' => ClassMetadataInfo::ONE_TO_MANY,
        ));
    
    // Getting form mapper in controller:
    $contractor = $this->container->get('sonata.admin.builder.orm_form');
    $mapper = new FormMapper($contractor, $this->admin->getFormBuilder(), $this->admin);

    $form_mapper = $mapper->add('reference', 'sonata_type_model_list', array(
            'translation_domain' => 'ReferenceBundle',
            'sonata_field_description' => $fieldDescription,
            'class' => $this->container->get('sonata.admin.reference')->getClass(),
            'model_manager' => $this->container->get('sonata.admin.reference')->getModelManager(),
            'label' => 'Reference',
            'required' => false,
        ));


    //@ToDo build $form from $form_mapper


    return $this->render('MyBundle:Form:field.view.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
  }
}
```

I cannot find any method in `Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper` class to build a form (it seems to be possible with `create()` method, but it only works with common Symfony field types, not Sonata form field types, which are commonly generated in Block or Admin classes).

Is it possible to use `Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper` in the Controller to build a form?
Or is there another way I can build a form with Sonata form field types in the Controller?

Comment: Why don't make your form using your Admin Class ? It is here for that

Answer (score 0):

You should not use a controller, rather a Sonata Admin Service.

Sonata provides you with the 'sonata_type_choice_field_mask' type which allows you to change the fields displayed on the form dynamically depending on the value of this 'sonata_type_choice_field_mask' input.

[Here is the doc](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/form_types.html#sonata-type-choice-field-mask) where you can find everything about sonata types and the choice field mask.

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper
        ->add('reference', 'sonata_type_choice_field_mask', array(
            'choices' => array(
                //The list of available 'Reference' here
                'choice1',
                'choice2'
            ),
            'map' => array(
                //What you want to display depending of the selected option
                'choice1' => array(
                    // List of the fields displayed if choice 1 is selected
                    'field1', 'field3'
                ),
                'choice2' => array(
                    // List of the fields displayed if choice 2 is selected
                    'field2', 'field3'
                )
            ),
            'placeholder' => 'Choose an option',
            'required' => false
        ))
        ->add('field1', 'sonata_type_model_list', array(/* Options goes here */))
        ->add('field2', 'url', array(/* Options goes here */))
        ->add('field3')
    ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have access to the admin which directly handles building the form with `Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\AbstractAdmin::getForm`.

```
$form = $this->admin->getForm();
```